# Is every parameter outside of the union of minimal primes?

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, maximal-and-prime-ideals, local-rings, dimension-theory-algebra

**Proposition 1:** Let $R$ be a commutative, Noetherian ring and $\ \mathfrak{p} \in \operatorname{Spec}(R)$. If $\operatorname{ht}(\mathfrak{p})=h$, then there exist $y_1, \ldots, y_h \in R$ such that $\ \mathfrak{p} \in \operatorname{Min}((y_1, \ldots, y_h))$.

I followed [this proof](https://www.niser.ac.in/%7Echitrabhanu/CA/Dimension.pdf) (Proposition 12, pg 5). The construction of the $y_i$ involves picking elements in $\mathfrak{p} \setminus \cup Q$, where $Q$ are the minimal primes of $R$. As a corollary, we get:

**Proposition 2**: Let $(R, \mathfrak{m})$ be a commutative, Noetherian, local ring of Krull dimension $d$. Then,

$$\dim R = \min \{c \mid \exists x_1, \ldots, x_c \in \mathfrak{m}, \ \sqrt{(x_1, \ldots, x_c)} = \mathfrak{m} \}.$$

**Definition**: Any $x_1, \ldots, x_d$ that verify $\sqrt{(x_1, \ldots, x_d)} = \mathfrak{m}$ are called a *system of parameters* (sop). An element $x$ is called a *parameter* if it belongs to a system of parameters. Proposition 1 guarantees the existence of a sop.

Thanks to the proof of Proposition 1, we know that every element of $\mathfrak{m} \setminus \cup Q$, where $Q$ is a minimal prime of $R$, is a parameter.

**Question**: Is every parameter also in $\mathfrak{m} \setminus \cup Q$ ? I get the feeling it is true but I'm not sure.

I've tried proving it straight away, picking a sop $x_1, \ldots, x_d$ such that $x_1 \in Q$, with $Q$ a minimal prime of $R$, and then using the sop given to us by Proposition 1, $y_1, \ldots, y_d$, such that no parameter is in the union of the minimal primes, but didn't go far.